# Query that Gets all data when an ID is the same

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table that returns me these results.

```
ProcessID   AddressID   ItemStateID
22             2            50
22             3            50
22             4            50
22             5            50
22             6            50
22             7            60
22             7            50
22             8            50
22             9            50
22             10           60
22             10           50
22             11           50
22             12           50
```

But what i want is this:

```
ProcessID   AddressID   ItemStateID
22             2            50
22             3            50
22             4            50
22             5            50
22             6            50
22             7            60
22             8            50
22             9            50
22             10           60
22             11           50
22             12           50
```

When the AddressID is the same i want to get the highest ItemStateID in one row...

For now this is the query i am using at the moment:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ProcessID,
    AddressID,
    ItemStateID
FROM MMResult2
WHERE ProcessID = 22 AND ItemStateID > 10
ORDER BY AddressID ASC, ItemStateID DESC
```

Comment: Use `Group By AddressID` and `MAX(ItemStateID)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `distinct` and group by the columns you want to be unique. To aggregate the last column use `max()`

```
SELECT ProcessID,
       AddressID,
       max(ItemStateID) as MaxItemStateID
FROM MMResult2
WHERE ProcessID = 22 
  AND ItemStateID > 10
GROUP BY ProcessID,
         AddressID
ORDER BY AddressID ASC, 
         max(ItemStateID) DESC
```

Comment: This is the one who worked best and nice explaining, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT 
    ProcessID,
    AddressID,
    MAX(ItemStateID)
FROM MMResult2
WHERE ProcessID = 22 AND ItemStateID > 10
GROUP BY AddressID
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `GROUP BY` and `MAX` Function.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ProcessID, AddressID, MAX(ItemStateID) AS HighestItemStateID
FROM MMResult2
WHERE ProcessID = 22 AND ItemStateID > 10
GROUP BY ProcessID, AddressID, 
ORDER BY AddressID ASC, ItemStateID DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    ProcessID,
    AddressID,
    MAX(ItemStateID)  AS ItemStateID 
FROM MMResult2
WHERE ProcessID = 22 AND ItemStateID > 10
GROUP BY ProcessID, AddressID
ORDER BY AddressID ASC, ItemStateID DESC
```